# GUI WinAPI Directory

Tags: c++, gui, ui

Как называется элемент интерфейса пользователя, который позволяет выбрать путь к файлу или директорию? Такой же элемент, который при установке программ, где папку выбирать. В WinAPI как его сделать или как он называется?

Comment: Это не элемент интерфейса, а диалог [`GetOpenFileName/A/W`](https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/windows/win32/api/commdlg/nf-commdlg-getopenfilenamea?redirectedfrom=MSDN)

Comment: @ヒミコ Спасибо большое!

Comment: @ヒミコ GetOpenFileName позволяет выбирать файлы, а директорию можно им выбрать или для этого другой диалог?

Comment: Посмотрите ссылки внизу страницы, там есть информация.